# why button which is created in useEffect doesnt work correctly

Tags: react-native

i have two button and they call same function like this:

this button created in useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
      TopRightButton: (
        <ConfirmButton
          callback={() => ApiCall()}
         
        />
      ),
    });
 
  }, []);
```

this is second button in render

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> ApiCall()}><Text>Add</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

this is function:

```
  const ApiCall = () => {
    console.log('name', Name);
  };
```

*i change name with useState. when i click TouchableOpacity which is second button, it shows me name. However, when i click first button which is  created in useEffect, nothing happen. i mean, Name is null. why this is happen ?*

any advice ?

EDITED:

```
  const [Name, setName] = useState('');
```

Comment: Try changing you function to `function ApiCall(){.....}`.

Comment: it is not work @GouravSaini

Comment: You need to pass `Name` / `ApiCall` in dependency array of `useEffect`. Add a `return cleanup function` if required.

Comment: Can you show me How should i do ? @GouravSaini

Comment: Where does `Name` come from? Can you show the whole code?

Comment: i added. it is just useState, i change it with TextInput, there is no more @Auticcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will u try this way?

```
const ApiCall = () => {
 console.log('name', Name);
};
useEffect(() => {
navigation.setParams({
  TopRightButton: (
    <ConfirmButton
      callback={() => ApiCall()}
     
    />
  ),
});

}, [Name]);
```

Comment: it didnt work :(  i give Name  here. [Name] it is work now. but this is bad way  ?

Comment: yes, because it re-renders the button every time `Name` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information concerning that first button, im guessing it is a button that you want to show on the right side of your stack navigator's header, if that's the case you should **NOT** use `setParams` for that.

If you want to configure your navigator you should use `navigationOptions`.

So in the screen where you want to add a button in its header, you have to call `setOptions` inside `useEffect` instead. Check out the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setparams) for more info on how to achieve that.

Comment: i am using react-navigation v4 :(

Comment: You can still achieve the same result the syntax is little bit different that's all. In your `createStackNavigator` method you should pass a second object as a paramter that contains the key `navigationOptions`, this key takes the exact same object you would normally pass to `setOptions` in react-navigation-v5. If you want any further help just tell me I'll edit my original answer.